# How to select dataframe specific day?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
           Open    Volume  Adj Close     Ticker  
Date 
2006-11-18  140.750000   45505300   114.480649   SPY 
2006-11-18  100.470001     274000   72.382071    AGG
2006-11-19  140.750000   45505300   114.480649   SPY 
2006-11-19  100.470001     274000   72.382071    AGG                                                                  
2006-11-22  140.750000   45505300   114.480649   SPY 
2006-11-22  100.470001     274000   72.382071    AGG
```

I use this cmd to select the row want I want:

"2006-11-22” is today.

df[df.index==today]

But I finally want to get the row 2006-11-19(Previous trade day).

I don't know the previos trade day is "2006-11-19".

I only know today is "2006-11-22”.

How to write this code？

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can do `df.loc['2006-11-19']` if the index is a datetimeindex

Comment: I don't know the previos trade day is "2006-11-19"

Comment: I'm not sure about your dates but you can do `d = dt.datetime(2006,11,22)
d = d - pd.offsets.BDay(1) df.loc[d]`

Comment: Could I get the 2006-11-22 row's number N and then use N-1 to get the row? But I don't know how to write this.

Comment: You can do `s = df.index.get_loc(dt.datetime(2006,11,22))` however, as you have a non unique index, this will give you a slice object so you need to call `first` on the slice object to return the index value, you can then subtract 1 from that value and do `df.iloc[]` with that index value

Comment: It may make more sense to set your index to the date and ticker so that you have a single date row associated with each ticker

Comment: Thanks your reply. How to use slice index=0 ?slice(0)?

Comment: so `s = df.index.get_loc(dt.datetime(2006,11,22))` then do `df.loc[df.index[s.start - 1]]` to return both rows with that index label

Comment: Thank you EdChum.You help me a lot.